# Traefik, how to disable check ACME certificate for host I didn't asked

Tags: traefik

I'm using traefik and I configured my certificate for my domain. It worked well! Problem is that traefik tries to ask certificate for container I didn't asked for.

For example, if it tries to ask certificate for my container postgres or redis. How can I configure traefik in docker in order to tell him to not make those action?

```
"Using HTTP Challenge provider."
time="2018-12-14T16:23:09Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"redis.docker\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:redis.docker\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [redis.docker]: acme: Error 400 - urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed - Error creating new order :: Name does not end in a public suffix"
time="2018-12-14T16:23:10Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"postgres.docker\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:postgres.docker\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [postgres.docker]: acme: Error 400 - urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed - Error creating new order :: Name does not end in a public suffix"
```

Those container are not even declared with traefik labels:

```
  postgres:
      image: postgres:9.4
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  otherImage:
```

And I configured traefic to not expose hosts by default. (traefik.toml)

```
# Enable Docker configuration backend
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

So how can I tell traefik to only create certificates for those who I asked  for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it can be done this way:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
```

[Lables description](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers)

Comment: Is this really the only way? I don't want to be required to set this just to prevent traefik from requesting certificates for random docker containers :/

Comment: @TeNNoX  I don't know. I move my apps to https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt stack, `traefik` looks very interesting, but badly documented(mess of old and new docs when I look at it last time)